# sharepoint 2010, exception handling httpmodule not working

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, exception, module

I've written the following HTTP module to catch ALL exceptions:

```
namespace Code.CapEx.Web.Framework.Http.Modules
{
  public class ExceptionHandlingModule : IHttpModule
  {
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
      context.Error += OnError;
    }

    private static void OnError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var exc = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
      ProcessException(exc.InnerException);
    }

    private static void ProcessException(Exception exception)
    {
      HttpContext.Current.Items["LastError"] = exception;
      EntLogger.Instance.Error(exception);

      if (exception is PermissionsException)
      {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/_layouts/MyProject/NotAuthorized.aspx");
      }
      else
      {
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("~/_layouts/MyProject/Error.aspx");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works perfectly on my dev machine (with no sharepoint) and really catches all exceptions.

But on QA machine, where this site works under sharepoint 2010 folder, exceptions are not caught at all!

What can be the problem source?
(I didn't forget to register http module in web.config ;))

Comment: maybe exceptions are caught, but redirections are not performed, and users can see the exception details.

Answer (score 0):

When an exception happens in SharePoint it is handled by SharePoint most of the time and then the user is redirected to a SharePoint error page with the details of the exception. Please investigate if this is your case.

To understand what I am talking about more precisely have a look at the methods
SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage(...) and how they are utilized in SharePoint.